# git add modified changes and don't ignore untracked files

Tags: git

First I add folder `nbproject` to `.gitignore`

Second I used `git rm --cached -r nbproject`

When I use `git status` I have:

`On branch newBranch

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
modified:   public/css/main.css
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
nbproject/private/config.properties
nbproject/private/private.properties
nbproject/private/private.xml
nbproject/project.properties
nbproject/project.xml`
```

And finaly when I use `git add .`, everything is added

How to do it, do not add what is in gitignore

Comment: This is a strange behaviour, but you have a typo in your question, which could explain it: you wrote `.gitignote` instead of `.gitignore`. Make sure the file is named correctly.

Comment: it's just a typo in the question, it's good in my project

Comment: Then it's very strange behaviour. I was not able to reproduce it. Can you provide the full contents of your `.gitignore` file? And edit the question to fix the typo?

Comment: of course I corrected the question. my .gitignore has only two lines : app\config\config.ini
nbproject\

Comment: maybe I have not added a file to the project, I will check it. First, I created the project then I added git and then created .gitignore

Comment: you said nbproject\ did you really mean it or did you mean nbproject/ which is perhaps what you want (based on the forward slash used in the untracked files part of your question.)

Comment: I used a bad slash. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments on the question, the issue here was a back slash instead of a forward slash was used with the directory name which caused the pattern in the line of the .gitignore file to not refer to the directory as expected

Here is a link to the gitignore documentation.
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore